# Android : How to enable or disable ADB?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, adb

I am very well aware with the fact that enabling and disabling ADB comes under Android security. Normal application wont be able to achieve that. But my case is different.

I am having full access to Android system. I have all the super user permission to do all the things from any of my application. I just want to implement one functionality in which I need to enable and disable ADB. If anyone knows how to achieve that please share with me.